# AirPlay to "iPhone Speaker" (iOS 7)

Tags: iphone, airplay, ios

So I upgraded to iOS 7 this morning. I checked Control Center a bit later and saw an AirPlay icon going to "iPhone Speaker". I have no idea why (we don't have any air play devices, let alone with that name), I don't know how it got selected, and I'm no longer seeing it. So… is that normal?

I noticed it again while playing a voicemail. It seems to directly control if the speakerphone is on or if it goes through the earpiece (not surprising really). But, can anyone explain what this has to do with AirPlay?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just makes it easier to locate where Airplay selection is. In other words, it is obvious you select it to change to Airplay.

Answer (score 0):

Try ending all running applications, it should go away. It's most probably because u have 2 music applications on. Hope this helps cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

The "AirPlay" section of Control Center does more than just the Apple AirPlay protocol.  It shows where sound is being output.  In this area, you might see:

- AirPlay:  *AppleTV Name*
- iPhone Speaker
- Dock Connector:  *Device-name*, perhaps your in-car System
- Bluetooth:  *Headset-name*

"Headphones" doesn't appear in the AirPlay section of the Control Center, but if you tap the button and click through to the AirPlay choices, "Headphones" will usually be a choice if they are connected.

[image]